# The buttons on the modal dialog box for leaving a page with unsaved changes are confusing

Tags: bug, status-declined, user-interface

If you are editing a question and decide to close the tab/window/whatever, SO opens up a dialog box asking you if you are sure. The buttons for this dialog are "OK" and "Cancel". However, what these map to is not entirely obvious. It would make more sense to change them to action words describing what they do. For example, it could be "Close this Question" and "Stay Here". This would eliminate the need to explain which button does what in the dialog itself and require less work from the user.

Answer (score 5):

I don't believe all browsers (or any) support changing the values of the buttons for the onunload event.

In Safari and Firefox it says "Click OK to continue, or cancel to say on this page", which should be enough of an explanation.

Comment: I was wondering if browsers supported changing this. But I don't know any JS so I defer to others' expertise.

Comment: Exactly - no need for my answer :)

Answer (score 5):

That modal dialog is the created via the window.onbeforeunload handler - the dialog's text is whatever string you return from the handler function.

Each browser has their own display for the "OK" and "Cancel" buttons, so we really can't control what's rendered.

Answer (score 0):

The dialog on Chrome seems to make enough sense to me.

[image: Confirm Navigation]