# Confusing dialog when cancelling an edit

Tags: bug, edits, cancel

When I cancel an edit, I get this dialog box:

[image: Cancel / OK]

(I'm using Chrome on Ubuntu if that matters.)

So I need to click "OK" to cancel the edit, and "Cancel" *not* to cancel the edit.

I initially suggested changing the labels on the buttons, perhaps to "Yes" and "No" to reflect the question being asked. But apparently the button labels are controlled by the browser.

The same problem still exists: The "cancel" link that's shown while editing has the opposite meaning of the "Cancel" button in the dialog box.

Given that, what would you think about changing the "cancel" link to something like "abandon edit"? (This doesn't apply to the [suggested duplicate question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13635/the-buttons-on-the-modal-dialog-box-for-leaving-a-page-with-unsaved-changes-are).)

Comment: This is pretty standard text. It should be pretty obvious if you only read the question part "Abandon this edit?"

Comment: Yes, but it pops up just after I clicked a link named "cancel". I'm not saying the current labels are wrong, just that they're potentially confusing.

Comment: It's not possible to change the options in that dialog. That is a confirmation dialog which is controlled by the browser. The only thing we can change in them is what text is displayed between the "stackoverflow.com says" and the buttons. We can't even change the styling of it.

Comment: @animuson: Bummer. Would it be possible to use a different kind of dialog, or would other kinds have different semantics that wouldn't work here?

Comment: @KeithThompson: Only a hand-implemented HTML dialog would be possible.

Comment: Duplicate is different dialog, but same reason for both request and decline...